# How to check if EEVEE or cycles is used?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Is there a way for a shader/material to check if it is being render in EEVEE or cycles? I want to activate different nodes that immitate or indicate some effects that don't work so well in EEVEE, for previewing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable *Material Output* for a specific render engine. This will allow you to create a single material with one material output for Eevee and one for Cycles.

[image]