# Accessing the Render Engine Type as a String from a Driver Expression

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, drivers

I am trying to make a Render Engine switch for node-trees, that will give control over ignoring or using certain node-chains depending on what render engine is used.

This is basically an improvement on this question's suggested answers. [Automatic material switch by Render Engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151160/automatic-material-switch-by-render-engine/204535)

My solution is trying to achieve this with a driver that looks at the name of the scenes designated render engine and compares it to a given string. In my example, this is 'CYCLES', but of course the switch could in this way be used to check for other engines as well.

Yes, I am aware this can be achieved by a node setup and by using the numeric position return value from the render engine enum, but these values will change if an engine is added to this list or removed from it. So a string check is much preferable.

[image: Render Engine Switch Node and Enum Values]
[image: Render Engine Switch Driver Setup]

The problem I am currently facing with this is, that I do not know how to access the name string from the enum. I can only get the position value from it.

If anybody has further insight into the datastructure, I would be much obliged.